# How can I unpack a pandas column for rows that have lists into a new row for each item in the list?

Tags: python, pandas

```
index   issues                                    count
0   Duplicates or higher volume found elsewhere     16
1   Location errors                                 13
2   Domain errors                                    4
3   [Location errors, Unapproved business models]    1
4   Unapproved business models                       1
5   [Domain errors, Location errors, Undetermined]   1
```

How can I turn the above dataframe into something like the one below?

```
index   issues                                    count
0   Duplicates or higher volume found elsewhere     16
1   Location errors                                 15
2   Domain errors                                    5
4   Unapproved business models                       2
5   Undetermined                                     1
```

Comment: What is your `pandas` version? Use: `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: And can you add the original dataframe? This looks like an aggregated dataframe after `groupby` or `value_counts`.

Comment: pandas version is: 0.22.0

that is correct. i called groupby on a column and used reset_index()

Comment: So I ask again: can you add the original dataframe, which is not aggregated.

Comment: @Erfan's request is right. It would be better do the unpacking before calling `groupby` rather than after it.